# gcc linking externs incorrectly?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm relatively new to gcc and I'm using 'gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0'. I've come across a very peculiar circumstance by mistake. I've shrunk my concern down to a very small reproducible example...

**main.cpp**

```
extern int g;

int main(){
    return g;
}
```

**someOtherFile.cpp**

```
#include<windows.h>

RECT g;
```

this I compile with

```
gcc -c someOtherFile.cpp
gcc main.cpp someOtherFile.o
```

and this will link without error.

Am I missing something here as to why this is allowed to link?

Comment: The `extern`al variable is defined elsewhere, so gcc searches for the definition and finds it in the `.o` file.

Comment: my concern is the type of g. g is defined as a RECT but declared as an int. an error should be thrown yes?

Comment: maybe `RECT` is just an alias of `int`? You should look up the definition of this type.

Comment: the definition is here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: using g++ also links without error. I was expecting an error so could it be the compiler is borked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.5/10:

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, except that declarations for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound (8.3.4).  A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

That last sentence means the compiler and linker are not required to give you an error message.  It's your job to get it straight.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm used to using the MS compiler and that throws an error.
Thankyou for citing the spec.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it won't link as the types of `g` are non-matching between main.cpp and someOtherFile.cpp. You have to have `int g` in someOtherFile.cpp or opposite, `extern RECT g;` in main.cpp.

In C this will compile and link, but on in c++.
Com compile and link as c++:

```
g++ -c someOtherFile.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o someOtherFile.o -o test
```

Alternatively, you may use functions for this:

**main.cpp**

```
int g();

int main{
    return g();
}
```

**someOtherFile.cpp**

```
#include<windows.h>

RECT r;
int g()
{
    return (int)r;
}
```

Obviously not recommended (as there isn't much point to cast RECT to int), but that would be similar in effect to what you were trying to do.

Variable `g` inside `someOtherFile.cpp` isn't related to the other `extern int g` declared in main.cpp. In effect, the `int g` simply isn't defined anywhere and linker will fail at the end for this reason.

Apparently, this will actually compile and link by g++, while microsoft linker will error on this type of mistake.

Comment: hiya, I don't want and wasnt expect it to link, I came across this by mistake and I was actually expecting an error. Using g++ it also links too without error :/

Comment: Oh, you should use g++ to compile and link. This code can be compiled as C and will link.

Comment: as I say, i can also compile and link with g++, could the compiler be borked?

Comment: @Dave Did you compile by g++ or by gcc? See updated answer to build it as c++

Comment: Yes, compile both files as the example but with g++ and it links

Comment: @Dave same here, used to ms compiler and totally surprised about this error with g++

Comment: I know. I'm blown away by this. You can literally use this to cast to anything. Whether its in the spec or not, I feel this is pretty poor as it's not as though the linker doesn't have the information needed for an error or a warning.

Comment: @Dave totally agree. I'm curious what would it do if there was `int g` in one file and then `float g` in another.

Comment: Just tried it. No matter the types it always links without question.

Comment: @Dave No, I'm saying what if you have someOtherFile.cpp with `RECT g;` and someOtherFile2.cpp with `float g`, not even sure if that's ok according tot the standard, while that is certainly ok with MS compiler.

Comment: The compiler then complains of a multiple definition. I would kind of expect this error as indeed the variable 'g' would be defined multiple times. I didn't know the ms compiler would allow this as I wouldn't expect it to work anyway.

Comment: Just for clarity... wen I say 'compiler' I mean 'compiler/linker' as a combined pair.